# MYSQL get First (MIN) and Last (MAX) order records grouped by user

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that stores all customer orders as follows (simplified for question):

```
+----------+---------------+------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | 
+----------+---------------+------+
| id (pk)  | int(10)       | NO   |
| cust_id  | int(10)       | NO   |
| total    | decimal(10,2) | NO   |
| created  | datetime)     | NO   |
+----------+---------------+------+
```

In one query, I wish to get each user's first ever order and the order total and their most recent order and that order total

So that I should have results like:

```
+----------+------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
| cust_id  | first_ord_total  | first_ord_date| last_ord_total   | last_ord_date |
+----------+------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
| 123      | 150.48           | 2018-03-01    | 742.25           | 2020-05-19    |
| 456      | 20.99            | 2019-08-01    | 67.22            | 2020-09-17    | 
| 789      | 259.99           | 2019-01-01    | 147.15           | 2020-08-31    | 
+----------+------------------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
```

I seem to be able to get the first and last order dates using MIN and MAX but I can't link it back to also give the order total from that same order/record

I know this is possible but I'm struggling to get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of MySql supports window functions, with MIN(), MAX() and FIRST_VALUE():

```
select distinct cust_id,
       first_value(total) over (partition by cust_id order by created) first_order_total,
       min(created) over (partition by cust_id) first_order_date,
       first_value(total) over (partition by cust_id order by created desc) last_order_total,
       max(created) over (partition by cust_id) last_order_date
from customers
```

Without window functions, use a query that retutns the first and the last order dates of each customer and join it to the table where you use conditional aggregation:

```
select c.cust_id,
       max(case when c.created = t.min_created then c.total end) first_order_total,
       max(case when c.created = t.min_created then c.created end) first_order_date,
       max(case when c.created = t.max_created then c.total end) last_order_total,
       max(case when c.created = t.max_created then c.created end) last_order_date
from customers c 
inner join (
  select cust_id, min(created) min_created, max(created) max_created
  from customers
  group by cust_id  
) t on t.cust_id = c.cust_id and c.created in (t.min_created, t.max_created)
group by c.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, `ROW_NUMBER` comes in handy here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY created) rn_first,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY created DESC) rn_last
    FROM orders
)

SELECT
    cust_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN total END)   AS first_ord_total,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_first = 1 THEN created END) AS first_ord_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN total END)   AS last_ord_total,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_last = 1  THEN created END) AS last_ord_date
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    cust_id;
```

The stategy here is to use `ROW_NUMBER`, per each customer, to identify the first and last transaction records, in a CTE.  Then, we aggregate by customer to find the first and last total amounts and dates.

Comment: Interesting, though should have mentioned I'm tied to 5.7.12 for the moment